# C# Webform, can GridView Select commandField display different text in each row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So I am working on a website and using GridView. There's one column which called "Status" (CommandField Select), is it possible to change the message inside that column differently for each row? So first row it display "Available", second row display "Sold" and both can be select to trigger the selectedindexchange.

Thanks!

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: There should be a way to do this. Please post some sample code (both view and backend) so that a reviewer knows where to give you advice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
Ok!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the `OnRowDataBound` event of the GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
```

Code behind

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //set the column which contains the edit buttons
    int columnWithEditButton = 0;

    //check if the row is a normal datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //get the linkbutton in the cell with findcontrol
        LinkButton lb = e.Row.Cells[columnWithEditButton].Controls[0] as LinkButton;

        //modify the text
        lb.Text = "Select " + e.Row.RowIndex;
    }
}
```